# Prove inequality involving elementary symmetric polynomial

Tags: inequality, roots, symmetric-polynomials

Let $n$ be a fixed number, such that $n \geq 2$, and  $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\sigma_{i}(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n})$ denote the i-th elementary symmetric polynomial in $x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}$. Prove that the following inequality is satisfied,

$ (i + 1) (n - i) \sigma_{i}^{2} \geq (i +2) (n-i+1) \sigma_{i+1} \cdot \sigma_{i-1}$

I am trying to use Newton's inequality, but I am getting stuck

Newton's inequality is , $i  (n - i) \sigma_{i}^{2} \geq (i +1) (n-i+1) \sigma_{i+1} \cdot \sigma_{i-1} $.

If  I substitute for n, and i they seem to work out.
For example, $n =3, i =1$,
From Newton's inequality, we know $ 2 \; \sigma_{1}^{2} \geq 6 \; \sigma_{2} \cdot \sigma_{0}$ is true, and the inequality I want to prove evaluates to $ 4 \; \sigma_{1}^{2} \geq 9 \;\sigma_{2} \cdot \sigma_{0}  $ which is true since $ 4 \; \sigma_{1}^{2} \geq  12 \; \sigma_{2} \cdot \sigma_{0}$ from Newton's inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For positive variables we have $$\frac{\sigma_i^2}{\sigma_{i-1}\sigma_{i+1}}\geq\frac{(n-i+1)(i+1)}{(n-i)i}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{(n-i+1)(i+1)}{(n-i)i}\geq\frac{(n-i+1)(i+2)}{(i+1)(n-i)}$$ or
$$(i+1)^2\geq(i+2)i.$$
Can you end it now?